# Export from JasperReports to Excel with more than 65532 rows

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to export a JasperReport report to xls with more than 65532 rows? It's possible to split the data in multiple worksheets? The JasperReports version is 4.0.1 and can't be updated (or changed).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All of these are possible.

What you need, to split the content on multiple sheets is to set a page break in the report, where you know it need's to start at, and set on the properties file, as well.

P.S.

If you want to see some code example, first show me some of your code. Just for a better adjusts and customization.